# Ellipse-detection algorithm

Tags: python, performance

The problem will take more than 2 minutes, so if you don't have much time I wouldn't recommend you to deal with the problem.

I found [this](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.1.8792&rep=rep1&type=pdf) paper on how to program "a new efficient ellipse detection method", so I thought why not just try it.   I programmed it in Python but my implementation is - in contrast to the title of the paper - really slow and needs for an 325x325 image (with 6000 black pixels), like this one [here](https://postimg.org/image/59faaui4f/), with multiple circles/ellipses on the order of 30 minutes...

Please read through my code and tell me where I can optimize things (and I think, that there are a lot of things to optimize).

I'll briefly explain the 15 steps, which are listed in the paper (if I explained one step unclear then just take a quick look at the paper):

**The steps:** (how I understood them)

1. Store all edge-pixels (pixels in black) in an array
2. clear the accumulator-array (you'll see the use of it later)
3. Loop through each array-entry in the "edge-pixels-array"
4. Loop through each array-entry again, check if the distance between the two coordinates (from step 3+4) is in between the min-radius and max-radius of my ellipse (min-radius and max-radius are just function parameters)

   If this is true, then proceed with steps 5-14.
5. Calculate the center, orientation and the assumed length of the major axis (you can see the equations on the paper, but I don't think that they are necessary)
6. Loop through each array-entry a third time, check if the distance between this coordinate and the assumed center of the point is between the min-radius and the max-radius. It this is true, then proceed with steps 7.-9.
7. Calculate the length of minor axis using equations (if you need to look them up on the paper)
8. Add the assumed parameters of the ellipse to the accumulator-array (center, x-Width, y-Width, orientation)
9. Wait for the inner (3.) `for` loop to finish
10. Average all values in the accumulator-array to find the average parameters for the investigated ellipse
11. Save the average ellipse parameters
12. Remove the pixels within the detected ellipse (so you don't check the pixels twice...)
13. Clear accumulator-array
14. Wait for the outer two `for` loops to finish
15. Output the found ellipses

I would be glad if someone could help me speed up the process because it takes a really long time.

```
import cv2
from PIL import Image
import math

def detectEllipse(filePath, minR, maxR, minAmountOfEdges):
    image = cv2.imread(outfile) # proceed with lower res.
    w, h = len(image[0]), len(image)

    # Ellipse Detection
    output = image.copy()
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    EdgePixel = []

    # Step 1 - Save all Edge-Pixels in an array
    for x in range(gray.shape[0]):
        for y in range(gray.shape[1]):
            if gray[x, y] == 0:
            EdgePixel.append([x,y])


    # Step 2 - Initialize AccumulatorArray and EllipsesFound-Array
    AccumulatorArray = []
    EllipsesFound = []

    # Step 3 - Loop through all pixels
    ignore_indices = set()
    for i in range(len(EdgePixel)):
        if i in ignore_indices:
            continue
        # Step 4 - Loop through all pixels a second time
        for j in range(len(EdgePixel)):
            if j in ignore_indices:
                continue
            if i != j:
            xAverage, yAverage, aAverage, bAverage, orientationAverage = 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
            # (Step 12, clear Accumulator-Array)
            AccumulatorArray = []
            
            tmp = math.sqrt(abs(math.pow(EdgePixel[i][0]-EdgePixel[j][0], 2)) + 
                  abs(math.pow(EdgePixel[i][1]-EdgePixel[j][1], 2)))
            distance = int(tmp)
            # Step 4.1 - Check if the distance is "ok"
            if(distance / 2 > minR and distance / 2 < maxR):
                # Step 5 - Calculate 4 parameters of the ellipse
                xMiddle     = (EdgePixel[i][0] + EdgePixel[j][0]) / 2
                yMiddle     = (EdgePixel[i][1] + EdgePixel[j][1]) / 2
                a           = tmp / 2
                if(EdgePixel[j][0] != EdgePixel[i][0]): # To prevent division by 0
                    orientation = math.atan((EdgePixel[j][1]-EdgePixel[i][1])/
                                            (EdgePixel[j][0]-EdgePixel[i][0]))
                else:
                    orientation = 0
                
                # Step 6 - Lop through all pixels a third time
                for k in range(len(EdgePixel)):
                    if k in ignore_indices:
                        continue
                    if len(AccumulatorArray) > minAmoutOfEdges:
                        continue
                    if k != i and k != j:
                        # Distance from x,y to the middlepoint
                        innerDistance = math.sqrt(abs(math.pow((xMiddle - EdgePixel[k][0]),2)) + 
                                        abs(math.pow((yMiddle - EdgePixel[k][1]),2)))
                        # Distance from x,y to x2,y2
                        tmp2 = math.sqrt(abs(math.pow((EdgePixel[i][0] - EdgePixel[j][0]),2)) + 
                                         abs(math.pow((EdgePixel[i][1] - EdgePixel[j][1]),2)))
                        
                        # Distance from x,y and x0,y0 has to be smaller then the distance from x1,y1 to x0,y0
                        if(innerDistance < a and innerDistance > minR and innerDistance < maxR):
                            # Step 7 - Calculate length of minor axis
                            
                            # calculate cos^2(tau):
                            tau = math.pow(((math.pow(a,2)+math.pow(innerDistance,2)-math.pow(tmp2,2))/(2*a*innerDistance)),2)  
                            bSquared = (math.pow(a, 2)*math.pow(innerDistance, 2)*(1-tau))/(math.pow(a, 2)-math.pow(innerDistance, 2)*tau)
                            # It follows:
                            b = math.sqrt(bSquared) # this is the minor axis length
                            
                            # Step 8 - Add the parameters to the AccumulatorArray
                            Data = [xMiddle, yMiddle, a, b, orientation]
                            AccumulatorArray.append(Data)
                # Step 9 (repeat from Step 6 till here)
                # Step 10 - Check if the algorithm has detected enough Edge-Points and then average the results
                if len(AccumulatorArray) > minAmoutOfEdges: 
                    # Averageing
                    for k in range(len(AccumulatorArray)):
                        tmpData = AccumulatorArray[k]
                        xAverage            += tmpData[0]
                        yAverage            += tmpData[1]
                        aAverage            += tmpData[2]
                        bAverage            += tmpData[3]
                        orientationAverage  += tmpData[4]
                    xAverage            = int(xAverage / len(AccumulatorArray))
                    yAverage            = int(yAverage / len(AccumulatorArray))
                    aAverage            = int(aAverage / len(AccumulatorArray))
                    bAverage            = int(bAverage / len(AccumulatorArray))
                    orientationAverage  = int(orientationAverage / len(AccumulatorArray))

                    # Step 11 - Save the found Ellipse-Parameters
                    EllipsesFound.append([xAverage, yAverage, aAverage, bAverage, orientationAverage])
                    
                    # Step 12 - Remove the Pixels on the detected ellipse from the Edge-Array
                    for k in range(len(EdgePixel)):
                        if ((math.pow(EdgePixel[k][0] - xAverage, 2) / math.pow((aAverage+5), 2)) + 
                               ((math.pow(EdgePixel[k][1] - yAverage, 2) / math.pow((bAverage+5), 2)))) <= 1:
                            ignore_indices.add(k)
    return

detectEllipses("LinkToImage", 5, 15, 100)
```

Here is a Profile of the program, with most time is spent in `pow2` (simply multiplies 2 values) and `math.sqrt`:

> ```
> 65082750 function calls (65080245 primitive calls) in 22.924 seconds  
> Ordered by: internal time
>
> ncalls      tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)  
> 1           17.666   17.666   22.724   22.724  ElipseDetection.py:16(detectEllipses)  
> 34239900    2.410    0.000    2.410    0.000   ElipseDetection.py:162(pow2)  
> 15660662    1.806    0.000    1.806    0.000   {built-in method math.sqrt}  
> 14612430/14612383    0.699    0.000    0.699   0.000 {built-in method builtins.len}  
> 488000      0.062    0.000    0.062    0.000     {method 'append' of 'list' objects}
> ```

Comment: The first thing you should do is run it with a profiler. Use `python -m cProfile script_name.py` to see where most of the time is being spent. Maybe you could also add a sample image/way to generate one?

Comment: https://postimg.org/image/59faaui4f/ here you can see an example-image and the profiler think I'll do later :)

Comment: As already stated, you should provide a full working example but as a pointer, your "going through" a third time actually means you're doing \$O(n^3)\$ operations because of the nested `for`s. That's 6000^3=216000000000 operations and you have no caching for all the divisions and power operations you're doing.

Comment: @ChatterOne I know, this one I calculated also! But I almost don't know anything about caching..

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Please do not update the code in your question to incorporate feedback from answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Answer (score 12):

#### Original points

> ```
> # Step 2 - Initialize AccumulatorArray and EllipsesFound-Array
> AccumulatorArray = []
> ```

It's not needed in this scope, and in the scope where it *is* used the first thing that happens is that it's reinitialised, so this line is completely pointless.

---

> ```
> for i in range(len(EdgePixel)):
>     if i in ignore_indices:
>         continue
>     # Step 4 - Loop through all pixels a second time
>     for j in range(len(EdgePixel)):
>         if j in ignore_indices:
>             continue
>         if i != j:
> ```

This should be one of `if i < j:` or `if j < i:` because otherwise any pair of points which is rejected as a major axis will be tested a second time with the indices reversed, doubling the workload.

---

> ```
>         xAverage, yAverage, aAverage, bAverage, orientationAverage = 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
> ```

What's the scope of these variables?

---

> ```
>         tmp = math.sqrt(abs(math.pow(EdgePixel[i][0]-EdgePixel[j][0], 2)) + 
>               abs(math.pow(EdgePixel[i][1]-EdgePixel[j][1], 2)))
>         distance = int(tmp)
>         # Step 4.1 - Check if the distance is "ok"
>         if(distance / 2 > minR and distance / 2 < maxR):
> ```

What are those `abs` for? It looks like you're trying to work around a bug in the standard library, but in that case you should document the bug clearly.

Why take the `sqrt`? As far as I can see `distance` isn't used anywhere else. Since `sqrt` is a monotonically increasing function over the range of interest you could instead square `minR` and `maxR` once and then compare the squared distances.

FWIW `distance` is also not a useful name in my opinion. `distanceIJ` would explain which of the many distances it is, but better still would be `majorAxis`.

---

> ```
>            # Step 5 - Calculate 4 parameters of the ellipse
>             xMiddle     = (EdgePixel[i][0] + EdgePixel[j][0]) / 2
>             yMiddle     = (EdgePixel[i][1] + EdgePixel[j][1]) / 2
>             a           = tmp / 2
>             if(EdgePixel[j][0] != EdgePixel[i][0]): # To prevent division by 0
>                 orientation = math.atan((EdgePixel[j][1]-EdgePixel[i][1])/
>                                         (EdgePixel[j][0]-EdgePixel[i][0]))
>             else:
>                 orientation = 0
> ```

Firstly, your indentation seems broken here. Before pasting code into any StackExchange site you should ensure that it has no tabs or that your tabstop is 4 spaces, because the indentation *will* be forceably converted to spaces using that tabstop.

This would be more readable with names for `EdgePixel[i][0]` etc. Could be `ax, ay, bx, by`, `xp, yp, xq, yq`, or anything simple and consistent.

The correct way to avoid division by zero is to use `atan2` instead of `atan`.

---

> ```
>             # Step 6 - Lop through all pixels a third time
>             for k in range(len(EdgePixel)):
>                 if k in ignore_indices:
>                     continue
>                 if len(AccumulatorArray) > minAmoutOfEdges:
>                     continue
>                 if k != i and k != j:
> ```

Check the spelling.

What's the second skip condition about? I don't see that in the algorithm description, and it seems to reduce the ability to discriminate between multiple candidate ellipses.

Why the inconsistent use of `continue` for two conditions and then a massive nested `if` block for the third? It would seem more consistent to write

```
            for k in range(len(EdgePixel)):
                if k in ignore_indices or k == i or k == j:
                    continue
```

and then lose a level of indentation on the main content of the loop.

---

> ```
>                     # Distance from x,y to the middlepoint
>                     innerDistance = math.sqrt(abs(math.pow((xMiddle - EdgePixel[k][0]),2)) + 
>                                     abs(math.pow((yMiddle - EdgePixel[k][1]),2)))
>                     # Distance from x,y to x2,y2
>                     tmp2 = math.sqrt(abs(math.pow((EdgePixel[i][0] - EdgePixel[j][0]),2)) + 
>                                      abs(math.pow((EdgePixel[i][1] - EdgePixel[j][1]),2)))
>                     # Distance from x,y and x0,y0 has to be smaller then the distance from x1,y1 to x0,y0
>                     if(innerDistance < a and innerDistance > minR and innerDistance < maxR):
> ```

Previous comments about `abs` and `sqrt` apply also here.

---

> ```
>                         # Step 8 - Add the parameters to the AccumulatorArray
>                         Data = [xMiddle, yMiddle, a, b, orientation]
>                         AccumulatorArray.append(Data)
> ```

What about `k`? If you store that you greatly simplify the update to `ignore_indices`, because it's simply a case of adding the `k` of the selected parameters from the accumulator rather than repeating the calculation to determine which points are on the ellipse.

---

> ```
>             # Step 10 - Check if the algorithm has detected enough Edge-Points and then average the results
>             if len(AccumulatorArray) > minAmoutOfEdges: 
>                 # Averageing
>                 for k in range(len(AccumulatorArray)):
>                     tmpData = AccumulatorArray[k]
>                     xAverage            += tmpData[0]
>                     yAverage            += tmpData[1]
>                     aAverage            += tmpData[2]
>                     bAverage            += tmpData[3]
>                     orientationAverage  += tmpData[4]
>                 xAverage            = int(xAverage / len(AccumulatorArray))
>                 yAverage            = int(yAverage / len(AccumulatorArray))
>                 aAverage            = int(aAverage / len(AccumulatorArray))
>                 bAverage            = int(bAverage / len(AccumulatorArray))
>                 orientationAverage  = int(orientationAverage / len(AccumulatorArray))
> ```

This is just wrong. The specification calls for you to find the most common minor axis (presumably with some margin of error, although that's not stunningly clear) and to take just the points which correspond to that minor axis as the points on the ellipse.

The details are a bit tricky. You're casting to `int` when producing the output of the parameters, so do you assume that all minor axes should be integers? If so, that makes the grouping relatively easy. Otherwise the easiest implementation would be to add a parameter `bMargin`, sort the values of `b` and scan to find the value of `b` which has most points in the range `[b, b + bMargin]`. Then if *that cluster* has `minAmountOfEdges` points, you take the points in the cluster, average their parameters to get the values for `EllipsesFound`, and add their `k` values to `ignore_indices`.

---

#### Additional points

> ```
>                     tmp2 = math.sqrt(abs(math.pow((EdgePixel[i][0] - EdgePixel[j][0]),2)) + 
>                                      abs(math.pow((EdgePixel[i][1] - EdgePixel[j][1]),2)))
> ```

This is another bug. It should be using `k` rather than `i`.

---

Why accumulate values of `xMiddle`, `yMiddle`, `a` and `orientation` and then take their averages? The only element of `Data` which actually depends on `k` is `b`, so that the only one that's worth accumulating and averaging.

---

By looking at how the results of `sqrt` were used and observing that they're nearly all squared again, it's possible to simplify a lot. This is steps 3 to 9 (admittedly with too few comments and needing a better name than `foo`):

```
ignore_indices = set()
for i in range(len(EdgePixel)):
    if i in ignore_indices:
        continue

    px, py = EdgePixel[i][0], EdgePixel[i][1]

    for j in range(len(EdgePixel)):
        if j <= i or j in ignore_indices:
            continue

        qx, qy = EdgePixel[j][0], EdgePixel[j][1]
        majorAxisSq = math.pow(px - qx, 2) + math.pow(py - qy, 2)

        if (majorAxisSq < minAxisSq or majorAxisSq > maxAxisSq):
            continue

        AccumulatorArray = []
        cx, cy = (px + qx) / 2, (py + qy) / 2

        for k in range(len(EdgePixel)):
            if k == i or k == j or k in ignore_indices:
                continue

            rx, ry = EdgePixel[k][0], EdgePixel[k][1]
            crSq = math.pow(cx - rx, 2) + math.pow(cy - ry, 2)

            # Require |C-R| < majorAxis and point not so close to centre that minor axis (< |C-R|) is too small
            if crSq > majorAxisSq or crSq < minAxisSq:
                continue

            # Calculate length of minor axis. TODO Numerical analysis
            var fSq = math.pow(rx - qx, 2) + math.pow(ry - qy, 2);
            foo = math.pow(majorAxisSq/4 + crSq - fSq, 2)
            bSquared = (majorAxisSq * crSq * (majorAxisSq * crSq - foo)) / (majorAxisSq - 4 * crSq * foo)
            minorSemiAxis = math.sqrt(bSquared)

            AccumulatorArray.append([minorSemiAxis, k])
```

#### Higher level suggestions

Looking at the filters it's become clear what the biggest speed improvement would be. There's a maximum permitted major axis; once you're looking for possible edge points, there's a constraint that every point must be inside the circle which has `EdgePoints[i]` and `EdgePoints[j]` as its diameter. Rather than scanning every single edge pixel to see whether it meets those criteria, you should find or implement a [geometric lookup data structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spatial_database). It doesn't necessarily have to support circular or semicircular lookups: bounding boxes should be good enough to reduce the points tested considerably. As a first implementation, unless there's suitable library support, I'd try a simple [quadtree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree).

Comment: Thanks, I have a few more questions: What Do you mean with geometric lookup Data structure? What's wrong with the average thing? What do you mean by "inconsistent use of continue"? Could you maybe explain? And could you explain step 10 in the paper:"If the vote is greater than the reqired least number for assumed ellipse, one ellipse is detected " because I don't unterstand it :/ (maybe you could add the points in your answer :))

Comment: @Gykonik, have you seen my first edit ([second revision](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/posts/154071/revisions#spacer-c4915458-975c-41ee-a2a5-031c167a1f70)), which expanded on the "inconsistent use of continue"? I've just made a third edit which adds some links to data structures and expands slightly on the other points you mention.

Comment: Perfect, i'll look through this tomorrow! :)

Comment: And what Do you think about caching? :)

Comment: And could you Explain step 10 in the paper? "If the vote is greater than the reqired least number for assumed ellipse, one ellipse is detected" I don't understand the meaing of this...

Comment: @Gykonik, I'm not convinced that there's much that can usefully be cached. To understand step 10, look again at step 8: "*Increment the accumulator for this length of minor axis by 1*". It seems that they're quantising the minor axis (and table 1 bears that out). So then in step 10 "*Find the maximum element in accumulator array*" means "Of the candidates for minor axis, find the one which maximises the number of points on the ellipse". But if no minor axis gives you at least e.g. 5 points, there isn't an ellipse at all and the agreement of e.g. 4 points is just random noise.

Comment: okay, I thought the same! Okay, I, I think, that I understand everything except for "_Increment the accumulator for this length of minor axis_". What should be stored in `accumulator`?

Comment: I think that the authors of the paper are using an array of ints for their accumulator, indexed by rounded-off semi-minor axis. But I think it makes more sense to store the exact calculated semi-minor axis (because the cluster may not be centered on an integer) and also to store the value of `k` (as an optimisation for removing the points). (I'm also starting to think that it would be better to take points `i`, `j`, and the ones from the winning cluster and put them into an ellipse best fit process rather than continuing to assume that points `i` and `j` define the major axis exactly).

Comment: Okay! Two questions, in your optimized code `bSquared` return negative numbers. I think, that you typed something wrong there. Also I wanted to ask, how you would make the "average"-Thing on which I'm currently failing. Maybe you could also add this to your optimized code! And again you don't know how greatful I am to you :)

Comment: And I added an second edit to my post :)

Answer (score 5):

Disclaimer: I don't do python

> ```
>             # Step 6 - Lop through all pixels a third time
>             for k in range(len(EdgePixel)):
>                 if k in ignore_indices:
>                     continue
>                 if len(AccumulatorArray) > minAmoutOfEdges:
>                     continue
>                 if k != i and k != j:
>                     # Distance from x,y to the middlepoint
>                     innerDistance = math.sqrt(abs(math.pow((xMiddle - EdgePixel[k][0]),2)) + 
>                                     abs(math.pow((yMiddle - EdgePixel[k][1]),2)))
>                     # Distance from x,y to x2,y2
>                     tmp2 = math.sqrt(abs(math.pow((EdgePixel[i][0] - EdgePixel[j][0]),2)) + 
>                                      abs(math.pow((EdgePixel[i][1] - EdgePixel[j][1]),2)))
> ```

You are calculating `tmp2` although you might not need it. If the condition `if(innerDistance < a and innerDistance > minR and innerDistance < maxR):` won't be true the calculation of `tmp2` would be superflous.

---

You are doing a lot of `math.pow()` and all of the calls are with the power of `2`. I bet implementing a method `pow2(value)` which returns `value * value` will be much faster.

Comment: Actually, `tmp2` just seems to be `tmp`, so the calculation is unconditionally superfluous.

Comment: Actually, correction, it's buggy. Should use `k` instead of `i`.

Comment: When I think about it again I'm not quiet shure, if `math.pow()`wouldn't be faster then `pow2()`because I think, that first one is very optimized and maybe also caches some calculations...

Comment: @Gykonik not quite sure if this is still valid, but you can check for yourself: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5246964/2655508

Comment: I have profiled `math.pow()` and `pow2()` in a range of `(0, 9999999)` with the result, that first one needed ~5,5s and second one needed ~2,5s. So this question is solved! :P

Answer (score 1):

## Too much indexing

Python is not a compiled language.  Every time something is indexed, the Python interpreter will redo the index lookup.  It cannot determine that a value is unchanged and there is no need to repeat the indexing.

Consider just the following statements:

```
    for i in range(len(EdgePixel)):
        ...
        for j in range(len(EdgePixel)):
            ...
            if ...:
                for k in range(len(EdgePixel)):
                    if k != i and k != j:
                        innerDistance = math.sqrt(abs(math.pow((xMiddle - EdgePixel[k][0]),2)) + 
                                        abs(math.pow((yMiddle - EdgePixel[k][1]),2)))
                        tmp2 = math.sqrt(abs(math.pow((EdgePixel[i][0] - EdgePixel[j][0]),2)) + 
                                         abs(math.pow((EdgePixel[i][1] - EdgePixel[j][1]),2)))
```

Since you have a triple-nested loop, the inner loop executes approximately \$N^3\$ times.  In just the `innerDistance` calculation, `EdgePixel[k]` is evaluated twice.  The first time to fetch the `EdgePixel[k][0]` value, and then a second time in order to fetch the `EdgePixel[k][1]` value.  This indexing is not a trivial operation.  Each time `EdgePixel` is first looked up in the local dictionary, then `k` is looked up in the local dictionary, then `PyObject_GetItem(PyObject *o, PyObject *key)` is called with those two value to fetch the value of `EdgePixel[k]`!

Since the values are not changing inside the loops, look them up once as you are looping in the `for` statement itself:

```
    for i, (xi, yi) in enumerate(EdgePixel):
        ...
        for j, (xj, yj) in enumerate(EdgePixel):
            ...
            if ...:
                for k, (xk, yk) in enumerate(EdgePixel):
                    if k != i and k != j:
                        innerDistance = math.sqrt(abs(math.pow((xMiddle - xk),2)) + 
                                        abs(math.pow((yMiddle - yk),2)))
                        tmp2 = math.sqrt(abs(math.pow((xi - xj),2)) + 
                                         abs(math.pow((yi - yj),2)))
```

Not only is the above faster, it is easier to read, as `[0]` and `[1]` have been replaced by more semantically meaningful `x` and `y` named variables.

## Move invariants out of loops

`tmp2` doesn't depend on `k`, or any other value from the innermost loop.  It can be computed outside the `k` loop.

```
    for i, (xi, yi) in enumerate(EdgePixel):
        ...
        for j, (xj, yj) in enumerate(EdgePixel):
            ...
            if ...:
                tmp2 = math.sqrt(abs(math.pow((xi - xj),2)) + 
                                 abs(math.pow((yi - yj),2)))
                for k, (xk, yk) in enumerate(EdgePixel):
                    if k != i and k != j:
                        innerDistance = math.sqrt(abs(math.pow((xMiddle - xk),2)) + 
                                        abs(math.pow((yMiddle - yk),2)))
```

Unless, of course, the calculation is incorrect and is supposed to depend on `k`, as indicated by Peter Taylor.  In that case, this movement is merely optimizing incorrect code. ;-)